# Shortcode and get_template_part

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, shortcode, single, get-template-part

I'm developing my own plugin for my wordpress. I create a shortcode for my plugin and CPT with a custom taxonomy and custom single-CPT.

When I try to use the function get_template_part() in my shortcode, the result is a call to a single.php template from the theme. How I can limit where get_template_part can look for files?

This is my shortcode:

```
function shortcode_display_products ( $atts ){

 global $wpdb;
 $query = '';

 $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
   'categories' => ''
 ), $atts, 'shortcode_display_products');


if( !empty($atts['categories']) && !is_null($atts['categories']) ){
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'     =>  'products',
  'post_status'   => 'public',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy'=> 'groups',
      'field'   => 'slug',
      'terms'   => '"'.$atts['categories'].'"'
    )
  ),
  'showposts'     =>  -1,
  'orderby'       =>  'date',
  'order'         =>  'DESC'
));
}
else{
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type'   =>  'products',
  'post_status' => 'public',
  'showposts'   =>  -1,
  'orderby'     =>  'date',
  'order'       =>  'DESC'
));
}
ob_start();

if( $query->have_posts() ){

  $c = 0;

  while ( $query -> have_posts() ){

      $query -> the_post();
      get_template_part('single','products');

    $c++;
 }
}
else{
 return esc_html__('Not found any product register',P_TEXTDOMAIN);
}

wp_reset_postdata();

return ob_get_clean();

}

add_shortcode('display_products','shortcode_display_products');
```

This is my single-products:

```
if ( !is_single() ){

 include '/form/products-form.php';
 $idnumber = ( is_single() )? '': '-'.$c;
?>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="heading<?= $idnumber?>">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?= $idnumber?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<?= $idnumber?>">
        <?= $post->title ?>
      </button>
    </h5>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse<?= $idnumber?>" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading<?= $idnumber?>" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      <?= $post->content ?>
      <?php create_product_form() ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php }
else{ _e('nothing else',P_TEXTDOMAIN);}

}
```

Comment: Note that when you do something like `<?= $post->content ?>` it's not escaped, but it's also unprocessed, so no shortcodes or embeds will work

Comment: thanks for the advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

Function `get_template_part()` **load file only from theme** directory (or child theme). 
There is no filter or action hook that would change this behavior.

You will need to write your own `get_template_part()` variant to load files from the plugin directory (replace the `locate_template()` call from the original function). Or write an explicit:

```
$query->the_post();
include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'single-products.php';
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I will try to do my own template_part :)